# Array filter without undoing the above structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, frontend

I'm having difficulty putting together an array filter that can contain exact and possible data, but the array has 2 layers, and I need to keep the first structure in case between the data in the second layer.
example json:

```
{
  OpenClientIndicator: false,
  listTypeCreditOffer: [{
         companyName: 'itau',
         offerCard: [{
                 nameCard: 'black',
                 idCard: 10,
                 availableValue: 10000.00
         },{
                 nameCard: 'platinum',
                 idCard: 9,
                 availableValue: 5000.00
         },....]
         id:1
       },{
         companyName: 'santander',
         offerCard: [{
                 nameCard: 'black',
                 idCard: 100,
                 valor: 15000.00
         },{
                 nameCard: 'platinum',
                 idCard: 90,
                 availableValue: 7000.00
         },....]
         id:2
       },...]
}
```

the filter will be on the nameCard and id Card, however I have to leave the structure above it intact, for example, the filter value is 10, a number, the return has to be like this:

```
{
  OpenClientIndicator: false,
  listTypeCreditOffer: [{
         companyName: 'itau',
         offerCard: [{
                 nameCard: 'black',
                 idCard: 10,
                 availableValue: 10000.00
         }
         id:1
       ]
}
```

when using this structure it does not scan all the arrays in the first layer and always stops at the first record that it thinks is not processing the other arrays.

```
let cards;
const newDados = jsonArray.listTypeCreditOffer.forEach((offer) => {
  cards = offer.offerCard.filter((card) => { 
       if( card.idCard.toString().includes(filtroValue.toUpperCase()) ||
           card.nameCard.toUpperCase().includes(filtroValue.toUpperCase())) {
           return card;
       }
  });
 });
```

This is where I'm getting stuck in the logic.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I haven't seen any problem with your filteration function.

Comment: In other words, you want to filter each `offerCard` array, and if that ends up empty, you want to remove the parent object from the `listTypeCreditOffer` array entirely…?

Comment: I need to filter the offercard and return its object, the other data that is not in the filter has to come out, I don't want the data outside the filter.

Comment: @Newbee In the function I created it cannot filter an array containing 10 parent array which is listTypeCreditOffer and more than 20 child arrays which in this case would be the offercard, the function enters the first array and finish, not going through the other arrays.

Comment: @HyagoLopes, As is said, no problem with your filteration function. So please clarify the question. I make your code [here](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/gOZqWvz) and there's no problem.

Comment: @Newbee The difficulty is connecting the card with the company, it's as if I took the original array and removed the cards that are not in the filter, that's my difficulty.

Comment: @HyagoLopes, If you can make an playground it helps easier to solve your problem. But If I'm not wrong, you have two filteration. (1) for **Company** and; (2) for **idCard**. I edit my code [here](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/gOZqWvz) but if you can clarify you point and make some code workaround, it will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need make the things carefully, use spread operator `...` to make a copy of the properties of the element, then define the property filtered

```
datafiltered = {
    ...this.data,   //all the properties of this.data
                    //but the listTypeCreditOffer will be

    listTypeCreditOffer: this.data.listTypeCreditOffer
      .map((x: any) => ({
        ...x,       //all the properties of this.data.listTypeCreditOffer
                    //but offerCard will be
                    //I "hardCoded" the condition
                    //you generally makes more complex expresion
                    //e.g. your
                    //card.idCard.toString().includes(filtroValue.toUpperCase()) ||
                    //card.nameCard.toUpperCase().includes(filtroValue.toUpperCase()))
                    
        offerCard: x.offerCard.filter((card: any) => card.idCard == 10),
      }))
      .filter((x) => x.offerCard.length > 0), //finally you only gets the 
                                              //offerCar array it's not empty
  };
```